# Find the transmission parameter A the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer

[image]

---

**My work:**

I am trying this from hours by all method I am getting answer 1.5.But answer given is option (A).

Please help me whats the mistak I am doing?

> ### Method 1
>
> [image]

---

### Method 2

> [image]

Comment: You have done this correctly. Moral: Never trust answer keys always :D

Comment: If I convert the resistances into conductances, and combine the 5 matrices (one for each resistor and one for the transformer), then I get a final matrix with the upper left corner value as A=.75, as a conductance value. Inverted into a resistance, this would be 1.333. (I do follow your approach. But since I'm not familiar with the terminology used in this area, I can't really help at this time.)

Comment: @jonk sir I am still getting 1.5 from other method also I did't get you approach.

Comment: @Rohit Agreed. I also completely agreed with your number, as well, and could see how you got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reflect the secondary load (2 + 5 ohms) back into the primary it becomes 7/4. The current in the primary of the transformer is V1/(2 + 7/4) = V1/3.75. The current in the secondary is 1/2 of that or V1/7.5.  V2 is just 5 times the secondary current or 5V1/7.5. If A = V1/V2, then A = 7.5/5 = 1.5. So you are correct and your book is in error.